# Dynamically assigning model value in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to pass the dynamically created model value to my controller. The div and model was created dynamically. But i can't fetch the model value in my controller.

This is the model part.

```
<div ng-repeat="cnt in countDiv">
    <div id="subDiv_{{cnt}}" >
        <select ng-model="Id_['{{cnt}}']" ng-change="getDetails(cnt)">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option ng-repeat="Data in details">{{Data.name}}</option>
        </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div> 
</div>
```

How can I get this model value`ng-model="Id_['{{cnt}}']"` in my controller ?

Answer (score 0):

I works for me

```
<div ng-repeat="cnt in countDiv">
<div id="subDiv_{{cnt}}" >
    <select ng-data-model="Id_{{cnt}}"ng-change="getDetails(cnt);">
        <option value="">Select </option>
        <option ng-repeat="Data in details">{{Data.name}}</option>
    </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: i need to get the    
    ng-model="Id_['{{cnt}}']"  
 inside getDetails(cnt) function in controller part dynamically. But i cant able to get the scope value of Id_['{{cnt}}']

Comment: I use ng-data-model to assign model for <select> dynamically. I think that you should add more  your controller code.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar as your for dynamic model .

```
   $scope.inputs = ['foo','bar'];
   $scope.filter={
    'foo':"Foo",
    'bar':"Bar"
   }
   });
```

and i implemented using ng-repeat like this

```
<div ng-repeat="filter in filters">
  <input type="text" ng-model= "'Id_'+ filter" />
</div>
```

If i understood you right, i have made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GqTuVg8ZjZ0250t3DQz7?p=preview) .This might help you.

Comment: in my case 'Id_' is a string value and only 'cnt' is changing but in your case both are varying. i tried Id_[cnt] but 'cnt' value is not coming. model value showing as Id_[cnt]

Comment: If Id_ isn't a variable in your case then my updated answer might help you.